# avr programming in atmel studio

Tags: c, avr

I have an error for this code in atmel studio
   the error is: `expected ')' before numeric` 
   and here is my code (I use this as a keypad code for atmega32a):

```
#include <util/delay.h>
#define c1 PINB 4 
#define c2 PINB 5 
#define c3 PINB 6 
#define c4 PINB 7

unsigned char scan[4]={0XFE,0XFD,0XFB,0XF7};
unsigned char arrkey[16]={1,2,3,20,4,5,6,30,7,8,9,40,10,0,11,50};

unsigned char keypad() {
    unsigned char r,c,k;
    DDRB=0X0F;
    PORTB=0XFF; 

    while(1) {
        for (r=0; r<4; r++) {
            c=4;
            PORTB=scan[r];
            _delay_us(10);
            if(c1 == 0) c=0;
            if(c2 == 0) c=1;
            if(c3 == 0) c=2;
            if(c4 == 0) c=3;

            if (!(c==4)) {
                k=arrkey[(r*4)+c];
                while(c1==0);
                while(c2==0);
                while(c3==0);
                while(c4==0);
                _delay_ms(50);
                return k;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you indent correctly your program?

Comment: At which line this error occurs?

Comment: in all if codes which has only one statement

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `#define` statements, because macro expansion shapes your code like this:

```
if(PINB 4 == 0) c = 0;
```

which is a syntax error, as PINB is defined as a register in the m32 definition file.
Maybe you meant `#define c1 PINB4` ?

Answer (score 0):

`PINB` is a 8-bit register and can be handled by bit-operation.
You can test some bits of `PINB` by using mask.
When you want to know whether the 4th bit of `PINB` is `0`, you can mask the `PINB` with `0b00010000`.
I guess you want to do the same thing by `#define c1 PINB 4`.

The 4 macros so can be defined as follows:

```
#define c1 (PINB & 0b00010000) //4th bit  
#define c2 (PINB & 0b00100000) //5th bit  
#define c3 (PINB & 0b01000000) //6th bit  
#define c4 (PINB & 0b10000000) //7th bit
```